# use \boxput (fancybox) as reminder: is there a way to change the relative coordinate system to the top of the box?

Tags: lengths, fancybox

I use the `fancybox`'s `\boxput` command to create reminder boxes in my documents. I like the fact about `\boxput`, that it lets you place a label above the box. This label is placed like a water mark, hence it does not take up any space.

Here is a quote from the documentation:

> The command
>
> ```
> \boxput*(x,y){LR stuff1}{LR stuff2}
> ```
>
> puts *LR stuff1* either behind (the default) or in front of (with
>   the*) *LR stuff2*. The resulting box has the dimensions of *LR
>   stuff2*.
>
> The coordinates `(x,y)` determine where the center of *LR stuff1* is
>   positioned. For example, `(0,0)` puts it at the center of *LR stuff2*,
>   `(0,1)` puts it at the center-top, and `(-1,-1)` puts it in the
>   bottom-left corner.
>
> More generally, the origin of the coordinate system is at the center
>   of *LR stuff2*, one unit in the vertical direction is half the
>   vertical size of *LR stuff2*, and one unit in the horizontal direction
>   is half the width of *LR stuff2*. Thus, `x` and `y` should always be
>   numbers (without units such as `pt` or `cm`), with one exception: If
>   `y` is `b` or `B`, *LR stuff1* is positioned vertically at the
>   baseline of *LR stuff2*. `(x,y)` is optional — the default is `(0,0)`.

My problem is, that `(0,0)` is at the center of *LR stuff2* (the text inside the box). I would want it to be at the top of *LR stuff2*. The problem for me is, that I would like to place *LR stuff1* as a title above the box. But since the positioning is relative to the center of *LR stuff2*, it moves, when *LR stuff2* becomes longer, hence I have to adjust the `y` coordinate manually.

Here is how I create the reminder boxes:

```
\newcommand{\reminder}[2][1.58]{%
 \begin{center}
   \Ovalbox{%
     \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}%
        \boxput(0.7,#1)%
          {\textcolor{gray!60}{\textbf{\Large R e m i n d e r}}}%
          {\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{~\\#2}}
     \end{minipage}%
   }%
 \end{center}%
}
```

Here is a picture to show you, what I am trying to say:

[image: Notice how the second reminder moves up, when the text inside the box becomes longer.]

Notice how the second reminder moves up, when the text inside the box becomes longer. The first reminder box is actually, what I am aiming for.

And finally here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\reminder}[2][1.58]{%
 \begin{center}
   \Ovalbox{%
     \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}%
        \boxput(0.7,#1)%
          {\textcolor{gray!60}{\textbf{\Large R e m i n d e r}}}%
          {\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{~\\#2}}
     \end{minipage}%
   }%
 \end{center}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2] 

\reminder{This is to remind you:
         \begin{equation}
           a \cdot b = b \cdot a
         \end{equation}
}

\lipsum[2]

\reminder{And now I remind you three times in a row:
         \begin{align}
           a \cdot b &= b \cdot a\\
           a \cdot b &= b \cdot a\\
           a \cdot b &= b \cdot a
         \end{align}
}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

As far as I can tell, I would have to calculate the distance from the center of the box to where I would like to place the *LR stuff1* and divide this by half the height of *LR stuff2*. But I have no clue, how to do that. Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to suggest you [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) instead; it oggers you endless customization possibilities and now your box admits page breaks (if you want to, otherwise, delete `breakable`):

[image]

The code (adjust the settings according to your needs):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{reminder}{
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  colback=white,
  colframe=black,
  arc=10pt,
  outer arc=10pt,
  boxrule=0.4pt,
  attach boxed title to top right,
  boxed title style={
    colback=white,
    empty
  },
  coltitle=gray!80,
  fonttitle=\Large,
  title=Reminder
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2] 
\begin{reminder}
This is to remind you:
         \begin{equation}
           a \cdot b = b \cdot a
         \end{equation}
\end{reminder}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{reminder}
And now I remind you three times in a row:
         \begin{align}
           a \cdot b &= b \cdot a\\
           a \cdot b &= b \cdot a\\
           a \cdot b &= b \cdot a
         \end{align}
\end{reminder}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was not aware of this package, thank you!

Comment: With `attach boxed title to top right=
{xshift=0mm,yshift=-0.7em}` the title may be positioned as desired.